# Replace worksheet name within the function in VBA in case of loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating several worksheets based on some worksheet *format* just simply copying all its content with formulas. Only I give a new name to the sheet.

I want that each time I create a sheet and giving it a name, *format!* word in all cells must be replaced with active worksheet name.

I tried to write some codes but it seems not working.

```
Sub createsheet()

    LastRow = Sheets("SUMMARY").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For i = 9 To LastRow
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = Left(Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(i, 1), 31)
        wsrepl = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name

        Sheets("format").Select
        Cells.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(i, 1)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 2) = Sheets("SUMMARY").Cells(i, 1)

        Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Activate
        Cells.Replace What:="format!", Replacement:= _
            wsrepl, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
            , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does adding `LookIn:=xlFormulas` in the replace statement help? Also, it would be helpful know what doesn't work.

Comment: You do not have to call ` Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Activate` twice at the end.

Comment: I tried it did not work out.

Comment: when you say that the *format!* should be updated, do you mean where this word is contained inside formulas, or are you talking pure text entries? The forumulae should update automatically when you rename the sheet with *wsrepl = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name*

Comment: Format! is the name of the sheet. So each time I create a new sheet it should be replaced with the created sheet name so the formulas work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         Cells.Replace What:="format!", Replacement:= _
       "'" & wsrepl & "'" & "!", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
        , MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I found an answer.